# return True for recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion, return, logic

could someone please indicate to me what's wrong with the logic of the simple recursive function, below:

def palindrome (string):

```
if len(string)<=1:
    return True
elif string[0]== string[-1]:
    palindrome(string[1:-1])
else:
    return False
```

the False part, works ok, for example :
palindrome('good') the function returns correctly False.
but if it's fed a palindrome like :
palindrome('level') the function returns nothing.

Comment: `palindrome(string[1:-1])` should be `return palindrome(string[1:-1])`

Comment: also, the function should be named `is_palindrome`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't return the function when calling it recursively, but you should, or the original function call will return None.

Solution:

```
def palindrome (string):
    if len(string)<=1:
        return True
    elif string[0].lower() == string[-1].lower():
        return palindrome(string[1:-1])
    else:
        return False
```

I would also add "lower" as capitalization isn't relevant